# Getting the order for categories.lft rgt

Tags: categories, order

While trying to assign a global CSS class based on the `order` of the categories based on the drag and drop in the admin editor.

The categories I'm using is a single 1 level deep category.

It seems like the `lft` and `rgt` values are the only one that changes when they are moved.

It appears I can just divide the `lft` number by `2` and I get a sequence of the order (1,2,3,4,5,6).

```
{%- for category in relatedCategories -%}
  <a href="{{ category.url | default }}"
    class="ArticleCard-meta-link ArticleCard-meta-link--{{ category.lft /2 }}"
  >{{ category.title }}</a>
{%- endfor -%}
```

How do the values `lft` and `rgt` get assigned and is this a correct assumption that dividing it will always get an incremental pattern?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but the pattern that Craft uses for structures and categories (things that have depth, hierarchy and order) is the Nested Set model. You can read about it and the math involved here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model